# Xcode 6 + Story Board with multiple views + handling keyboard events

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a Xcode 6 app using Swift with multiple views. The app consists of a series of screens gathering user responses.

I want am triggering keyboard on the UIViews when they load by setting the UITextFields as first Responders. I have registered listeners in the following fashion to respond to Keyboard events, because there are controls, a custom menu bar, on the bottom of the screen which needs to slide up.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        childAge.becomeFirstResponder()

        //Register for keyboard notifications in order to reposition bottom menu
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "kbShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "kbHidden:", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)

    }
```

Then I remove the listeners in the viewWillDissapear Event.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)

}
```

These code blocks are repeated in all UIViewController classes. However, my problem is, the kbShown functions gets triggered properly only in the first view. In subsequent views, though the events get fired, the menu bar does not get displayed as intended.

```
func kbShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary

    let s:NSValue = info.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as NSValue;
    let rect :CGRect = s.CGRectValue(); //this is the KB rect

    //Get Screen Size
    var screenRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds // [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    var screenWidth = screenRect.size.width
    var screenHeight = screenRect.size.height

    var frame = self.menuBar.frame;
    frame.origin.y = screenHeight - rect.height - frame.height //menuY! - rect.height;
    self.menuBar.frame = frame;

}  

func kbHidden(notification: NSNotification) {

    var screenRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds // [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    var screenWidth = screenRect.size.width
    var screenHeight = screenRect.size.height

    var frame = self.menuBar.frame;
    if (frame.origin.y != screenHeight - frame.height){
        frame.origin.y = screenHeight - frame.height //frame.origin.y + rect.height;
        self.menuBar.frame = frame;
    }   
}
```

My MenuBar view is still hidden under the keyboard. But if I interact with the KB and if I adjust its height (in IOS8 there is a predictive text bar that can be dragged down) then the menuBar view starts to appear fine.

Also, if I set my second view as the first view controller, everything works fine. Lost a couple of days over this and any help is appreciated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I noticed that the KeyBoard Hidden in the second view gets fired when transitioning from the first view to the second view. But the the first views event doesnt get fired, because by then the listeners on the first view are de-registered.

Comment: Soon after the keyboard hidden is fired, the keyboard shown event is fired. Does that have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you register your observer in the `viewDidLoad` method and remove them in `viewWillDisappear` after the first disappearing the keyboard handling method aren't going to be called again, until viewDidLoad is.
This happens because in the view controller life cyle `viewDidLoad` is called only when the view needs to be loaded not when is displayed. The next time the same view can be loaded again is when the view controller is deallocated or probably during a memory warning event when the view is not visible.

The best place to register your VC as observer of keyboard notification is the `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Hi, I did change that. But still the same behaviour. Tried registering then in both viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear.

Comment: If you do like that the first time you'll receive two notifications.